# Why does jersey have no error log when the status is 500?

Tags: jersey-2.0

This is my web.xml:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>rest</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And this is my resource class:

```java
@Path("/main")
public class MainResource {

    @XmlRootElement
    public class Planet {
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public double radius;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Planet getPlanet() {
        final Planet planet = new Planet();

        planet.id = 1;
        planet.name = "Earth";
        planet.radius = 1.0;

        return planet;
    }
}
```

And when I run the tomcat server, the log is like this:

```text
09-Jan-2015 13:19:10.501 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-8] org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.log 1 * Server has received a request on thread http-apr-8080-exec-8
1 > GET http://localhost:8080/rest/main
1 > accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
1 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
1 > accept-language: en,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.6
1 > connection: keep-alive
1 > cookie: JSESSIONID=69F79D567E7ECA27A129C477B91C7758
1 > host: localhost:8080
1 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36

09-Jan-2015 13:19:10.597 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-8] org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.log 1 * Server responded with a response on thread http-apr-8080-exec-8
1 < 200
1 < Content-Type: application/xml

09-Jan-2015 13:19:10.794 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-8] org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter.log 2 * Server responded with a response on thread http-apr-8080-exec-8
2 < 500
```

I wonder why it shows 500 error, but I cannot find any error log about the exception stack.

Please help me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I fixed my issue and I answer my own question now.

First, how can I enable the exception trace logging?

```java
@Provider
public class ExceptionMapper implements javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).build();
    }
}
```

Yes, we should implement an ExceptionMapper on my own.

Second, what's the error of my code?

The class Planet should be static.

Comment: This unfortunately disables all other exception mappings, e.g. makes 500 instead of 404 for `javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException`

Comment: After continuing research on the source code, seems that the only solution on the Jersey framework users' stance, i.e. without changing source code, is `implements javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper`, but still am skeptical about the implementation above