# How to make Jersey Application print the error log in the Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs, trace

In the context of *Jersey* **2.25.1**, a very simple REST API is built with a simple *JAXB* *POJO* bean:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Profile {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
    //setter and getter
}
```

and a *resource*

```
public class ProfileResource {
    @Path("/profile")
    @Produce(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Profile getProfile() {
        Profile p = new Profile();
        p.setName("test");
        return p;
    }
}
```

and it is running on a *Tomcat* server.

A bug is in the *POJO* - *Profile* - deliterately so that when sending *http request* to **`localhost:8080/contextroot/profile`**, I would get an *internal error* response with *STATUS 500*. However, the **ERROR detail is not written into the default log file in the backend Tomcat server**. By comparison, with *Spring* framework all errors will be logged.

According to the [Jersey Documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/2.25.1/user-guide.html#tracing.configuration), *tracing support* can be *enable*d by set `jersey.config.server.tracing.type`  to `ALL`. So I `extends` the `jax.ws.rs.core.Application` as the following:

```
@ApplicationPath("contextroot")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ServerProperties.TRACING, TracingConfig.ALL.toString());
        System.out.println("Appliction is getting properties::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

with the `jaxrs-ri` dependency according to [How to set up JAX-RS Application using annotations only (no web.xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373081/how-to-set-up-jax-rs-application-using-annotations-only-no-web-xml). So this class is indeed instantiated when starting the application on the *Tomcat* server. However, when debugging on the the first line in `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(final ContainerRequest request)` class, i.e. `TracingUtils.initTracingSupport(tracingConfig, tracingThreshold, request);`, the value of property `jersey.config.server.tracing.type` was detected to be still `OFF` when sending a request, meaning the *`ApplicationConfig` is not used at all*.

**Question: How to enable the tracing support of a Jersey application on the Tomcat server**

**NOTE!** There is a rough answer in [Why does jersey have no error log when the status is 500?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854367/why-does-jersey-have-no-error-log-when-the-status-is-500/27854944#27854944) However, this answer will turn all the errors into *internal error with status 500*, which is unexpected obviously